# How to display revenue generated by a product from WooCommerce on the frontend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, donations, wordpress-ecommerce

I am trying to display certain text on a website I am working on that is donations based. It uses WooCommerce and WordPress to handle the donations.

I am trying to display the text "Raised so far: $xx" dynamically so it shows the amount raised but I am struggling to find anything on Google/Stackoverflow that would give me the solution to this problem.

Does anyone know of a plugin that exists for this or some code that could make this possible? Thank you in advance.

***Edit: See updated solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72876513/display-total-revenue-of-a-product-id-in-woocommerce-shortcode)***

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am some ways into getting this solved, have found a plugin, "Woo Shortcodes Kit" in the WordPress plugin repository which has something very close to what I'm looking for.

I need to make a custom function for a shortcode to do the calculation for an individual product ID, rather than all products (as an existing option within the plugin)