# Display Total Product Sales By Product ID WooCommerce Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Looking to display the total product sales of a specific product on the homepage as a shortcode, But the code I'm using Doesn't display anything once implemented

I am using [Display total revenue of a product id in WooCommerce shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72876513/display-total-revenue-of-a-product-id-in-woocommerce-shortcode/72883171#72883171) answer code, but It Displays Nothing. 
Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm Not sure Familiar With Coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
function total_sales_by_product_id( $atts ) {
    
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
  'id' => ''
), $atts );

$units_sold = get_post_meta( $atts['id'], 'total_sales', true );
 
return $units_sold;
 
}

add_shortcode( 'sales', 'total_sales_by_product_id' );
```

Use the shortcode [sales id="99"], where "99" is your product ID.